# Change ul style when arriving to div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I would like to change a ul style on scrolling and arrive to div using jQuery, explanation down.

CSS:

```
#menu {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.menutext {
    padding:25 40 30 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menutext2 {
    padding:25 40 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    color:red;
}

.alldivs {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:a9a9a9;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV1</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV2</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV3</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV1">DIV1</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV2">DIV2</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV3">DIV3</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
```

I want to change the div with the class "menutext" to class "menutext2" on scrolling and arriving to the top of the divs(first ul's class change from menutext1 to menutext2 on arriving to the div with the id DIV1, second ul's class change from menytext1 to menutext2 on arriving to the div with the id DIV2 AND the first ul's class return to menutext1 AS IT WAS and so on.